# Вместо скриншота - черная картинка

Tags: windows, screenshots

Почему в некоторых играх, когда делаешь скриншот (когда игра в полноэкранном режиме), в буфер обмена попадает просто черная картинка.

При чем в одной и той же игре на одном компьютере скриншоты делаются нормально, а на другом - черный экран.

Скриншоты делаются через PrtScr. Игра - Warface. Если важно - в игре используется DirectX11 (кто-то мне говорил, что это играет роль).

ОС: Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение 1**
Всё из-за того, что игра в полноэкранном режиме.
Можешь сделать оконный режим, и нажать PrtScr.

> Не помогло!

**Решение 2**
Проблема может быть в разрешении экрана. Например при ровных: 1920х1080 всё делается нормально, например при 1920х1000, нет.

> Но у меня ровное разрешение!

**Решение 3** Дело в самой игре, некоторые игры могу на одном устройстве поддерживать скриншот в играх, а некоторые нет.

> Но ничего из решений не работает!

Тогда я не в силах помочь.

**Заметка:** DirectX ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, ничего из этого не помогло. Скриншот нужен именно в полноэкранном режиме, разрешение 1920x1080. Похоже, дело действительно в самой игре.

Answer (score 0):

Установил ScreenMaster 2.11 -  пару дней пользовался все было норм, на следующий день как обычно делаю скриншот находясь в игре, нажимаю  PrtSc сделать скриншот,  но получаю скриншот с черным экраном а так же может просто рабочий стол скриншот ) и весит 16 килобайт место должных 160, перепробовал все что мог, ничего не миняиеться. И тут я вспомнил, что внес изменения в видео опшин -  Multisample 24 bit x4 maximum,  а было Multisample 24 bit x1, я вернул настройки на  x1  и  программа стала работать делать скриншот в игре.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lic7g.jpg